# How do I create a table with fixed left and right columns and horizontal scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a scheduling system and am having trouble with the grid. I want to have a `table` whose left and right `th` cells are fixed in place, but be able to scroll horizontally through the body `td` cells. The number of body `td` cells per `tr` is dynamic and can shrink and grow as the number of appointments in a time slot increases or decreases. I've looked around and found similar questions here, but they only ask for the left column to be fixed, where as I need both. I tried adapting what I saw in the answers, but it's not working.

My current prototype, here: https://jsfiddle.net/by2r6pkh/1/; is failing badly so I figured I'd ask for help. For what it's worth I'm only targeting Chrome for the browser.

Comment: I'm fine with JavaScript. I'm using jQuery 2.2.3 for the rest of the scheduling functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible in CSS alone, but it doesn't take much JavaScript.

Change your TH elements from `position: absolute` to `position: relative`.  That will resolve the problem with the wrapper's height, so you can remove `overflow-y: visible`.  It also resolves the problem with the TH elements' height.

You can also remove:

- `position: relative;` from the wrapper.
- `margin-left: 55px` from the table.
- `left: 0;` from th:first-child.
- `right: 0;` from th:last-child.

**Vanilla JavaScript solution:**

```
var wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

function scrollTable() {
  var thl = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper th:nth-child(1)'),
      thr = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper th:nth-last-child(1)');

  for(var i = 0; i < thl.length; i++) {
    thl[i].style.left = wrapper.scrollLeft + 'px';
    thr[i].style.right = wrapper.scrollWidth - wrapper.offsetWidth - wrapper.scrollLeft + 'px';
  }
} //scrollTable

wrapper.addEventListener('scroll', scrollTable);

scrollTable();
```

```js
var wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

function scrollTable() {
  var thl = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper th:nth-child(1)'),
      thr = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper th:nth-last-child(1)');

  for(var i = 0; i < thl.length; i++) {
    thl[i].style.left = wrapper.scrollLeft + 'px';
    thr[i].style.right = wrapper.scrollWidth - wrapper.offsetWidth - wrapper.scrollLeft + 'px';
  }
} //scrollTable

wrapper.addEventListener('scroll', scrollTable);

scrollTable();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  margin: 32px;
}
.wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  /* scrolls the entire table, not just the tds */
  width: 400px;
}
table {
  font: 14px arial;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  /* fixes column widths, but overflows */
  width: calc(100% - 110px);
  /* 2x left margin */
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  padding: 2px;
}
td {
  background: #FFF;
  width: 150px;
}
th {
  position: relative;
  background: #EEE;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>12:00
        <br />pm</th>
      <td>{CONTENT}</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <th>12:00
        <br />pm</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>12:30
        <br />pm</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <th>12:30
        <br />pm</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

---

**jQuery solution:**

```
$('.wrapper')
  .scroll(function() {
    $('.wrapper th:nth-child(1)').css('left', this.scrollLeft);
    $('.wrapper th:nth-last-child(1)').css(
      'right', this.scrollWidth - this.offsetWidth - this.scrollLeft
     );
  })
  .scroll();
```

```js
$('.wrapper')
  .scroll(function() {
    $('.wrapper th:nth-child(1)').css('left', this.scrollLeft);
    $('.wrapper th:nth-last-child(1)').css('right', this.scrollWidth - this.offsetWidth - this.scrollLeft);
  })
  .scroll();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  margin: 32px;
}
.wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  /* scrolls the entire table, not just the tds */
  width: 400px;
}
table {
  font: 14px arial;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  /* fixes column widths, but overflows */
  width: calc(100% - 110px);
  /* 2x left margin */
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  padding: 2px;
}
td {
  background: #FFF;
  width: 150px;
}
th {
  position: relative;
  background: #EEE;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>12:00
        <br />pm</th>
      <td>{CONTENT}</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <th>12:00
        <br />pm</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>12:30
        <br />pm</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <th>12:30
        <br />pm</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe the following link can help you.

https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html